# Is this a legal/safe way to pull data from websites on iOS?

Tags: html, ios, database

After playing around with a few different ways to pull website data I developed this simple and quick solution that appears to work well:

```
int zip = 13153;
int lowerBound = 10000;
int upperBound = 99999;
bool foundValidZip;

@implementation ViewController


- (void)viewDidLoad {
[super viewDidLoad];

while (foundValidZip == false) {
    zip = lowerBound + arc4random() % (upperBound - lowerBound);

    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    NSString *urString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://www.zip-info.com/cgi-local/zipsrch.exe?zip=%i&Go=Go",zip];
    NSURL *URL = [NSURL URLWithString:urString];

    NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:URL];

    // Assuming data is in UTF8.
    NSString *html = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:[data bytes]];

    NSLog(@"%@",html);

    NSMutableArray *names = [self stringsBetweenString:@"</th></tr><tr><td align=center>" andString:@"</font></td>" andText:html];
    NSMutableArray *states = [self stringsBetweenString:@"</font></td><td align=center>" andString:@"</font></td><td align=center>" andText:html];

    if ([names count] > 0 && [states count] > 0) {
        NSString *name = [names objectAtIndex:0];
        NSString *state = [states objectAtIndex:0];

        self.nameLabel.text = name;
        self.stateLabel.text = state;
        self.zipLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i",zip];
        foundValidZip = true;
    }

    else {
        foundValidZip = false;
    }
}

}

-(NSMutableArray*)stringsBetweenString:(NSString*)start andString:(NSString*)end andText:(NSString*)text {

NSMutableArray* strings = [NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:0];

NSRange startRange = [text rangeOfString:start];

for( ;; )
{

    if (startRange.location != NSNotFound)
    {

        NSRange targetRange;

        targetRange.location = startRange.location + startRange.length;
        targetRange.length = [text length] - targetRange.location;

        NSRange endRange = [text rangeOfString:end options:0 range:targetRange];

        if (endRange.location != NSNotFound)
        {

            targetRange.length = endRange.location - targetRange.location;
            [strings addObject:[text substringWithRange:targetRange]];

            NSRange restOfString;

            restOfString.location = endRange.location + endRange.length;
            restOfString.length = [text length] - restOfString.location;

            startRange = [text rangeOfString:start options:0 range:restOfString];

        }
        else
        {
            break;
        }

    }
    else
    {
        break;
    }

}
NSLog(@"%@",strings);
return strings;

}
```

Essentially what this is doing is querying a website that looks up the city that a ZIP codes are associated with, then fetching the HTML for a random ZIP code. The program then extracts specific bits of information from that HTML data by searching for text between a unique set of front and end "caps". I've used this "cap" method for a few other sample applications. Some of these do not actually query the website, but fetch data off of a static URL that is updated frequently. One of the only pitfalls I can see here is that if the HTML changes, this may not work. But other than that, it seems to work really well and is extremely quick. Before I publish any of my applications, I want to ensure that a large amount of queries will not damage the websites, or other disadvantages for both me and the webmaster. Is this OK to do? And is there a better alternative? (not for this specific purpose - ZIP codes - but just for pulls in general)

Comment: As you point out, this technique is "fragile" - it can break if the website layout changes. also, I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the answer to whether it is "legal" is not a programming question - it is a legal question that depends on the policies of the site in question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're doing is called scraping the web site / page. It's a general approach, but one that isn't ideal and comes with a number of pitfalls...

Generally speaking, you're better off not having any scraping code inside your app, because your app will take quite a while to change and redeploy to the store if the website changes and you need to update.

So, it's best to either have a server of your own do the scraping and then provide your 'sanitised' version of the data to the app, or to use a reconfigurable 3rd party service (like [Kimono](https://www.kimonolabs.com), I've never used it but the website is colourful) to abstract your app from the nitty gritty.

As for the users, your app / service is just like a normal user, so the website needs to be able to handle the number of users in general.

I agree with the comment from @paulw11 about legality if you don't own / have a relationship with the website involved - you should have a relationship with them...

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. I'll try and stick to local databases or my own servers from now on. I think you're also right about the legal portion. It's probably best not to be involved, lest someday they check their statistics and wonder where all those queries are coming from.

Comment: The Kimono thing is very intriguing. It appears to be essentially the same principal, so maybe the legality of it isn't an issue.

Comment: The legal thing is also about data ownership / copyright / etc, it's a much bigger deal than most people give credit for